# How to remove numbers from strings in a list using one single for loop in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Have this code where I'm trying to remove all the numerical characters from strings in file names. It seems everything going all right but file names don't change.

```
import os

files_list = os.listdir('/mnt/c/Users/maverick/Desktop/prank/prank')
for file_name in files_list:
    count = 0
    l = []
    for char in file_name:
        if not char.isdigit():
            l.append(char)
    new_string = ''.join(l)
    print('New string: ' + new_string)
    print('Old file name: ' + file_name)
    file_name = new_string
    print('New file name: ' + file_name)
    count = count + 1

print(files_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `rename` you can use `os.rename()`. Also, to remove all numbers from the file names you can use `maketrans` on digits from `string` like this.

```
import os
from string import digits

path = '/mnt/c/Users/maverick/Desktop/prank/prank'

files_list = os.listdir(path)
new_files_list = []

remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)

for file_name in files_list:
    count = 0
    new_string = file_name.translate(remove_digits)
    new_files_list.append(new_string)
    print('New string: ' + new_string)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join(path, new_string))
    print('Old file name: ' + file_name)
    file_name = new_string
    print('New file name: ' + file_name)
    count = count + 1

print('Old Filenames :', files_list)
print('New Filenames :', new_files_list)
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But I don't quite understand how the maketrans() method works. In official python's documentation is very brief explanation where it's syntax described as str.maketrans(x[, y[, z]]). What's it the commas after square brackets? How can novice understand something outta there? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans

Answer (score 0):

You could acheieve that using [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
files_list = os.listdir('/mnt/c/Users/maverick/Desktop/prank/prank')

processed = [''.join([c for c in name if not c.isdigit()]) for name in files_list]
```

Example:

```
files_list = ["abc", "abc1", "a2b3c4"]

processed = [''.join([c for c in name if not c.isdigit()]) for name in files_list]

print(processed) # >> ['abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```

**Update**

If your real purpose is to rename your files, you need the [os.rename()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm) method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the file itself, not just write the new string into old file name inside you script. You could use [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename):

```
import os
path = '/mnt/c/Users/maverick/Desktop/prank/prank'
files_list = os.listdir(path)
for file_name in files_list:
    count = 0
    l = []
    for char in file_name:
        if not char.isdigit():
            l.append(char)
    new_string = ''.join(l)
    print('New string: ' + new_string)
    print('Old file name: ' + file_name)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join(path, new_string))
    print('New file name: ' + file_name)
    count = count + 1

print(files_list)
```

Comment: This code produces - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory